# FormData Returns empty data on form submission in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events, form-data

I am trying to get the form data key-value pair object when the form is submitted, using the `new FormData()` constructor. But it always returns empty data.

I have already tried `event.persist()` to avoid react event pooling, but nothing worked

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    const data = new FormData(target);
    console.log(data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />

        <button>Send data!</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I am expecting an object that contains my form data in the following format

`{ "username": "Value" }`

Comment: FormData doesn't provide Properties like that. Try `console.log(...data)` or the methods that [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) provides to modify/access data.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you need to fetch it through looping. Try this

```
  var formData = new FormData(target);

   for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
   console.log(key, value);
  }
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

handleSubmit should be like this.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    fetch('my-api', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  }
```

After form submit, in network tab you will find form data with key-value.

If you want to access single value,

```
const username = data.get('username');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to use this generic code snippet

```
    const form = event.target;
    const data = {};
    for (let i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        const elem = form.elements[i];
        data[elem.name] = elem.value
    }
```

I don't know the reason of this behaviour but it may be because the input inside form are not a part of the DOM anymore

Answer (score -1):

one of
if you are using React, just use htmlType tag

```
<Form.Item>
  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" />
    Submit action
  </Button>
</Form.Item>
```